# Singular error in C++

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     int somma[9],k=0,f=11;
     somma[k]=somma[k]+f;
     cout << "somma:" << somma[k];
     system("PAUSE"); 
 }
```

This is my code. I expect output value "11" but getting "10". 
Why do I get this error?

Comment: please correct your code

Comment: where is the problem

Comment: you have an answer now :) see it

Answer (score 2):

With `somma[k]+f`, you are reading the value of an **uninitialised** element of the array `somma[0]`. The behaviour on doing that is *undefined*. So the output could be anything.

The solution is to write `int somma[9] = {};` instead, which sets all the elements to 0. If you need portability with C, then write `= {0};` instead.

Also it's a good idea to explicitly return a value from `main()` in C++.

You also need a line break before `using namespace std;` but presumably that's due to the way you've posted your code.

Comment: ok first the error is i fast write the code. But i dont understand i should write in somma[k]=0;

Comment: You may add spossible solution - initialize array as other variables.

Comment: @user3520954 `int somma[9] = {};` would initialize your array with zeros

Comment: @Slava: Yes, I've just added that.

Comment: and why i cant use somma ?

Comment: You can't read any variable in C++ until you've initialised it.

Comment: @user3520954 you cannot read from uninitialized variable, for example if you would not initialize `f=11;` and use it you will have the same problem

Comment: i have write int somma[9],but probably i should write int somma[9] = {}; is correct ?

Comment: That is exactly correct. But older compilers might require = {0}

Comment: #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;
      int main(){
 int v[9],s[9],k=0;
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
  cout << "Inserisci numero "<<" posizione " << i << endl;
  cin >> v[i];
 }
 for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
  s[k]=v[i]+s[k];
  cout<<"questo e il vettore"<<v[i]<<endl;
  cout<<"questo e la somma"<<s[k]<<endl;
 }
 system("pause");
          }
 But in this code write correctly without initializeted

Comment: @user3520954 You can't investigate undefined behavior, and expect that the same thing will always happen. Undefined means undefined - don't rely on what it does in any particular occasion.